# Time Machine stuck on "Preparing Backup"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, time-machine, backup

I have a MacBook Pro from 2009. It came with OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) but I upgraded to 10.8 (Mountain Lion).

A few days ago, I tried to backup my files on an external hard drive, like I have successfully done many times before and after the OS upgrade.

The status on the Time Machine menu at the top of my screen said "Preparing Backup", instead of counting up like it usually does. It stayed that way for a few minutes, then I got tired of waiting and stopped the backup.

Last night, I tried it again and let it sit overnight for almost 12 hours. It is still stuck on "Preparing Backup". **What can I do to make the backup work like it did before?**

I tried Googling for this problem and the solutions I saw said to either wait longer (without any clear idea of how long) or to exclude the Backups.backupdb folder from my virus scanner (which doesn't apply to me since I don't have a virus scanner).

**Edit on 2013-5-23:** Here are all the things I tried that didn't work:

- I tried waiting for the indexing to finish but that didn't seem to help. I let my laptop sit for about 36 hours and the status still said "Preparing Backup".
- I found a folder on my backup drive named `/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Elias Zamaria’s MacBook Pro (2)/2013-04-30-182726.inProgress`. I deleted it and that didn't seem to help.
- I tried verifying my main hard drive using the Disk Utility and everything seemed fine. I tried verifying the disk permissions and got some errors involving iTunes (I think), and I fixed them by clicking the "Repair Disk Permissions" button. I also tried verifying my external hard drive and it seemed fine. I tried the backup again and it froze like before.
- I tried looking at the website that @lgsancho linked to. I found some things that may look useful but I didn't try them yet.
- I tried running `tmutil status`, without the backup running and got this result:

  ```
  Backup session status:
  {
      ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
      Running = 0;
  }
  ```

  I started the backup, waited for the status to change to "Preparing Backup", and ran the same command, and got this result:

  ```
  Backup session status:
  {
      BackupPhase = ThinningPreBackup;
      ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
      DateOfStateChange = "2013-05-21 19:09:06 +0000";
      DestinationID = "8BC5795A-0AAC-4976-B960-ECCE8F48842C";
      DestinationMountPoint = "/Volumes/Time Machine Backups";
      Percent = "-1";
      Running = 1;
      Stopping = 0;
  }
  ```

  The backup has been going on for about 45 minutes. I tried the command and got this result:

  ```
  Backup session status:
  {
      BackupPhase = ThinningPreBackup;
      ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
      DateOfStateChange = "2013-05-21 19:09:06 +0000";
      DestinationID = "8BC5795A-0AAC-4976-B960-ECCE8F48842C";
      DestinationMountPoint = "/Volumes/Time Machine Backups";
      NumberOfChangedItems = 483816;
      Percent = 0;
      Running = 1;
      Stopping = 0;
  }
  ```

  It looks exactly the same, except the `Percent` has increased from "-1" to 0.
  The backup has been going on for almost 3 hours. The status still says "Preparing Backup" and `tmutil status` gives me exactly the same result as the last time.

Here are the things that have been suggested, which I am reluctant to try:

- Emptying my trash. I don't want to do this because it defeats the purpose of the trash and takes away my ability to recover files that I may have accidentally deleted.
- Deleting old backups. I may try this if nothing else I can think of is helpful.

**Edit on 2013-6-1:** I am unaccepting my answer because it is happening again. I will get sick of rebooting every time it happens. I just want it to stop. I am thinking of considering deleting my old backups. This is what I see in the Console from backupd:

```
5/31/13 11:09:09.595 PM com.apple.backupd-helper[16259]: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
6/1/13 12:09:37.920 AM com.apple.backupd-helper[16438]: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup - time machine destination not resolvable.
6/1/13 12:23:20.619 AM com.apple.backupd[16473]: Starting automatic backup
6/1/13 12:23:21.794 AM com.apple.backupd[16473]: Backing up to: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb
6/1/13 12:23:26.430 AM com.apple.backupd[16473]: Using file event preflight for Macintosh HD
6/1/13 12:23:55.148 AM com.apple.backupd[16473]: Will copy (829.8 MB) from Macintosh HD
6/1/13 12:23:55.602 AM com.apple.backupd[16473]: Found 14880 files (949.2 MB) needing backup
6/1/13 12:23:55.632 AM com.apple.backupd[16473]: 2.44 GB required (including padding), 391.84 GB available
6/1/13 9:06:02.191 AM com.apple.backupd[16473]: Cancellation timed out - exiting
6/1/13 9:10:04.406 AM com.apple.backupd[18634]: Starting automatic backup
6/1/13 9:10:05.055 AM com.apple.backupd[18634]: Backing up to: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb
6/1/13 9:10:11.788 AM com.apple.backupd[18634]: Using file event preflight for Macintosh HD
```

Comment: Let us know if the question here already has your answer. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54216/time-machine-stuck-on-preparing-backup-whenever-returning-from-boot-camp-to-os

Comment: Do not reuse the old backup. Use a newly formatted drive.

Comment: @bmike, I looked at the question you linked to. I am not using MacDrive or accessing the drive from a Windows computer or using it for any purpose other than Time Machine backups. I tried waiting for the indexing to finish but it was stuck for 36 hours. I tried deleting the inProgress folder like one solution suggested and it didn't seem to do anything. I will verify the volumes when I get a chance.

Comment: @EliasZamaria I am encountering this issue now, just after updating to macOS 10.12. I have verified my volumes on the sources and destination and everything exits successfully. In my case, however, the `percent` remains at `-1`. Did you ever determine a cause or solution?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't normal, but you have two options:

1. Just wait for all the processing to finish or error out.
2. Help the process along.

In this case, an initial backup can take a long time, but the way to help the process along is to delete the .../whatever.inProgress file. You could also try backing up to a new drive to make sure it's not a problem with the Mac as opposed to a problem with the backup drive or just a lot of changes to reconcile.

See this other answer for details.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/65801/5472

In cases where you run into this repeatedly, you can either try to isolate what folder takes so long to back up. On a first backup, I've tried to exclude the Users folder (or several folders at the base of the boot volume if they have more than 10 GB of data) to make sure that the filseystem is OK and the backup drive is OK. At that point, you will see backups taking a minute or so for each incremental backup. You can then relax the exclusion list and know if it freezes, then you have a problem in a specific folder.

The other way to attack this is run disk utility (or another tool) to repair the directory structure or make a back up using another tool and wipe the drives / restore them from backup.

Comment: I waited for almost 12 hours. How much longer do I have to wait?

Comment: I will try deleting the inProgress file the next time I feel like trying to make this work.

Comment: You can also use the command line tool `tmutil status` to dump exactly how far in the process you are. 12 hours could be perfectly fine if you are backing up 85 GB over a network connection. It would be abnormal for 5 GB over USB.

Comment: I found a file named `/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Elias Zamaria’s MacBook Pro (2)/2013-04-30-182726.inProgress` and moved it to the Trash, then started doing the backup as usual. I will let everyone know as to how it went and accept this answer if it helps.

Comment: The backup should proceed well. Once it's finished, empty the trash. That can take a very. Long time so perhaps empty over night.

Comment: I seriously need to empty the trash? What for?

Comment: I tried the backup again and it appeared to have frozen. I will try it again and wait longer when I have a chance.

Comment: I tried the backup again and let it sit for about 36 hours. It appeared frozen on "Preparing Backup" so I think I will give up on trying the advice in this answer.

Comment: I am reluctant to empty my trash because it seems like it would defeat the purpose. I would have no way of getting back anything I have accidentally deleted. I will be willing to delete specific things from my trash.

Comment: I tried verifying my main hard drive using the Disk Utility and everything seemed fine. I tried verifying the disk permissions and got some errors involving iTunes (I think), and I fixed them by clicking the "Repair Disk Permissions" button. I also tried verifying my external hard drive and it seemed fine. I tried the backup again and it froze like before.

Comment: Also note that the "Preparing backup" may need a lot of bandwith to the drive - if you can give it a cabled connection instead of wireless, it may be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Successively run:

```
tmutil status
```

And look at NumberOfChangeItems:

```
$ tmutil status
Backup session status:
{
BackupPhase = ThinningPreBackup;
ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
DateOfStateChange = "2014-12-14 16:32:00 +0000";
DestinationID = "25933E19-B889-4FAF-B421-53AFE4C68B58";
DestinationMountPoint = "/Volumes/Time Machine Backups";
NumberOfChangedItems = 92229;
Percent = 0;
Running = 1;
Stopping = 0;
}

$ tmutil status
Backup session status:
{
BackupPhase = ThinningPreBackup;
ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
DateOfStateChange = "2014-12-14 16:32:00 +0000";
DestinationID = "25933E19-B889-4FAF-B421-53AFE4C68B58";
DestinationMountPoint = "/Volumes/Time Machine Backups";
NumberOfChangedItems = 349457;
Percent = 0;
Running = 1;
Stopping = 0;
}
```

As long as the number is moving you are making progress.

Comment: There is no `NumberOfChangedItems` but `backupd` has been at 53% for hours

Answer (score 1):

I just rebooted my laptop and started the backup. It worked fine.

I have no idea why this works but at least I have some idea what to try if I have this problem again.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem encountered by me as mentioned by OP.

However, after performing the following steps, it worked like a charm:

> 1. Open your Time Machine drive in the Finder, select and delete the `.inProgress` file:
>
>    [image]
>
>    (enter your username and password, or an administrator's username and password, if asked to do so) and reboot your Mac, as mentioned [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/KvxZJLEi-UM?start=0&end=50).
> 2. Before connecting your external HDD for backup, open Terminal
>    and execute the following code:
>
>    ```
>    sudo mdutil -a -i off
>    ```
>
>    to disable Spotlight, as mentioned in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312200/389538).
> 3. Connect your external HDD to your computer and start the
>    backup.

Now please, be patient, give it around `30 minutes`.

Even now if the backup is still stuck in "Preparing backup" then:

> Execute the second line of code given in the [above linked answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312200/389538) (that is,
> enable Spotlight again):
>
> ```
> sudo mdutil -a -i on
> ```
>
> **while "Preparing for backup" is still running**.

In my case, I waited for `45 minutes` after following the above steps, and then finally my Mac started its backup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it helps to delete an old backup. I struggled around with the same problem and solved it by deleting the oldest backup. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39287/how-can-i-manually-delete-old-backups-to-free-space-for-time-machine) how to do that.

Comment: Are you sure I should delete my oldest backup and not my latest one? How would that help?

Answer (score 0):

A very useful page about Time Machine: http://pondini.org/OSX/Home.html

Comment: If you would like to expound on what that link has to say about the issue at hand, hat would be ideal. Link only answers are better as a comment to the question.

Comment: I saw a lot of stuff on that site. What exactly is useful on it? Any specific pages?

Comment: For troubleshooting about Time Machine you should take a look at http://pondini.org/TM/Troubleshooting.html

Comment: Specific help about TM stuck while preparing backup can be found at http://pondini.org/TM/D1.html

Comment: This link is now dead, so that's not very useful

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the reason why OP had the issue, but since this question appears high in the search result, I have another possible cause: the [Disk Activity monitor of MenuMeters](https://github.com/yujitach/MenuMeters/issues/19) polls the disk too often and completely blocks TM.

Simply disabling that monitor (while keeping the CPU, memory and network monitors) fixes the problem.

Comment: Is this only relevant is you have installed MenuMeters?

Comment: @SwisherSweet Other software might have the same issue, I don't know. But MenuMeters certainly blocked my TM backups until I disabled its Disk monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found a solution below.. hope this helps others.

For me, it was stuck on “preparing to restore…” for 5+ hours, seemed strange so I gave up this method and tried another route…

The problem, I realized now, was that my time machine backup was from macOS Catalina version, but when I booted in recovery mode, my Mac automatically downloaded the latest OS version (Monterey at the moment).

The solution: I installed Catalina on a bootable drive (download from App Store), and then I booted/installed from USB… once you go through that flow there will be an option to restore from time machine, and then the restore will work

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a normal issue. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65486/how-to-fix-slow-spotlight-and-time-machine-after-upgrading-to-10-7-5), the first backup is expected to take a long time…

Comment: Either way, this worked for me, and it is a plausible solution. If it will work for him, I don't know, but it is an answer. Long answers not always are the best.