# Time Machine does not complete ‘preparing backup’ step and shows no progress

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, high-sierra

I am stuck on ‘preparing backup’. I have tried to cancel the inProgress folder in the backups but still Time Machine doesn't work. Time Machine is just stuck for hours and I do not see any progress at all in the backup. The hard drive for the backup has a lot of free space.

I have tried all the potential solutions given in [Time Machine stuck on "Preparing Backup"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90478/time-machine-stuck-on-preparing-backup) but the backup is still unable to proceed.

MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013), High Sierra 10.13.4.

Comment: @grg I have updated my question. This question is not a duplicate because it regards high sierra, and it doesn't have an answer, because none of the receipts given work for me

Comment: The macOS version doesn't matter, the preparing backup stage does take many many hours for a large backup. What does `tmutil status` say about the backup?

Comment: What @grg said is true. Just to put it in perspective, it took 5-6 hours to prepare a 30GB backup on a MBP 2011. The actual backup took max an hour.